# Image Not Displaying Inside function Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

This is my code. I was trying the Standard Calculator but the mic image button is not at all displayed. I have not completed my entire code. Standard calculator body  is given in def Standard(). Please give me a solution.  The icon of the standard calculator is being displayed but the mic button is not shown at all. Still i would like to add Scientific Calculator with almost the same code. Also if anyone has date calculator to find the difference between two dates with calendar date picker, can you send the link. It would be a great help

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label, messagebox, Toplevel, Menu, END
import math
from pygame import mixer
import speech_recognition
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

    
def Standard():
        
    mixer.init()


    def click(value):
        ex = entryField.get()  # 789 ex[0:len(ex)-1]
        answer = ''
        

        try:

            if value == 'C':
                ex = ex[0:len(ex) - 1]  # 78
                entryField.delete(0, END)
                entryField.insert(0, ex)
                return

            elif value == 'AC':
                entryField.delete(0, END)

            elif value == '√':
                answer = math.sqrt(eval(ex))

            elif value == 'π':
                answer = math.pi

            elif value == 'cosθ':
                answer = math.cos(math.radians(eval(ex)))

            elif value == 'tanθ':
                answer = math.tan(math.radians(eval(ex)))

            elif value == 'sinθ':
                answer = math.sin(math.radians(eval(ex)))

            elif value == '2π':
                answer = 2 * math.pi

            elif value == 'cosh':
                answer = math.cosh(eval(ex))

            elif value == 'tanh':
                answer = math.tanh(eval(ex))

            elif value == 'sinh':
                answer = math.sinh(eval(ex))

            elif value == chr(8731):
                answer = eval(ex) ** (1 / 3)

            elif value == 'x\u02b8':  # 7**2
                entryField.insert(END, '**')
                return

            elif value == 'x\u00B3':
                answer = eval(ex) ** 3

            elif value == 'x\u00B2':
                answer = eval(ex) ** 2

            elif value == 'ln':
                answer = math.log2(eval(ex))

            elif value == 'deg':
                answer = math.degrees(eval(ex))

            elif value == "rad":
                answer = math.radians(eval(ex))

            elif value == 'e':
                answer = math.e

            elif value == 'log₁₀':
                answer = math.log10(eval(ex))

            elif value == 'x!':
                answer = math.factorial(ex)

            elif value == chr(247):  # 7/2=3.5
                entryField.insert(END, "/")
                return

            elif value == '=':
                answer = eval(ex)

            else:
                entryField.insert(END, value)
                return

            entryField.delete(0, END)
            entryField.insert(0, answer)

        except SyntaxError:
            pass

    def add(a,b):
        return a+b
    def sub(a,b):
        return a-b

    def mul(a, b):
        return a * b
    def div(a, b):
        return a / b

    def mod(a, b):
        return a % b

    def lcm(a,b):
        l=math.lcm(a,b)
        return l

    def hcf(a,b):
        h=math.gcd(a,b)
        return h

    operations={'ADD':add,'ADDITION':add,'SUM':add,'PLUS':add,
                'SUBTRACTION':sub , 'DIFFERENCE':sub , 'MINUS':sub , 'SUBTRACT':sub,
                'PRODUCT': mul, 'MULTIPLICATION': mul,'MULTIPLY': mul,
                'DIVISION': div, 'DIV': div, 'DIVIDE': div,
                'LCM':lcm , 'HCF':hcf,
                'MOD':mod ,'REMAINDER':mod , 'MODULUS':mod }


    def findNumbers(t):
        l=[]
        for num in t:
            try:
                l.append(int(num))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return l

    def audio():
        mixer.music.load('music1.mp3')
        mixer.music.play()
        sr = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
        with speech_recognition.Microphone()as m:
            try:
                sr.adjust_for_ambient_noise(m,duration=0.2)
                voice=sr.listen(m)
                text=sr.recognize_google(voice)

                mixer.music.load('music2.mp3')
                mixer.music.play()
                text_list=text.split(' ')
                for word in text_list:
                    if word.upper() in operations.keys():
                        l=findNumbers(text_list)
                        print(l)
                        result=operations[word.upper()](l[0],l[1]) #mul(5.0,6.0)
                        entryField.delete(0,END)
                        entryField.insert(END,result)

                    else:
                        pass


            except:
                pass





    win = Toplevel()
    win.title('Smart Calculator')
    win.config(bg='Cornflower Blue')
    win.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    win.geometry('394x477+100+100')
    p = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'logo.ico.png')
    win.iconphoto(False, p)

    entryField = Entry(win, font=('times new roman', 18, 'bold'), bg='grey80', fg='black', bd=10, width=18, )
    entryField.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, padx = 4)

    micImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'mic1.png')
    micButton = Button(win, text = audio, bd=0, bg='Cornflower Blue', activebackground='dodger Blue4',command=audio)
    micButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

    button_text_list = ["C", "AC", "√", "+", "π", "cosθ", "tanθ", "sinθ",
                        "1", "2", "3", "-", "2π", "cosh", "tanh", "sinh",
                        "4", "5", "6", "*", chr(8731), "x\u02b8", "x\u00B3", "x\u00B2",
                        "7", "8", "9", chr(247), "etn", "deg", "rad", "e",
                        ".", "0", "%", "=", "log₁₀", "(", ")", "x!"]

    lblDisplay = Label(win, text = "SCIENTIFIC CALCULATOR",font=('elephant',18,),
                       bg='Cornflower Blue',fg='White')
    lblDisplay.grid(row=0, column= 4,columnspan=4)

    rowvalue = 1
    columnvalue = 0
    for i in button_text_list:

        if i == "C":
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='orange', fg='black',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i == "AC":
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='orange', fg='black',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in "()":
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='Burlywood', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in "0123456789":
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='Light Yellow', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in ["cosθ", "tanθ", "sinθ", "cosh", "tanh", "sinh"]:
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='khaki', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in [ chr(8731), "x\u02b8", "x\u00B3", "x\u00B2"]:
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='spring green3', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in ["π", "2π"]:
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='orchid1', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in ["deg", "rad"]:
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='firebrick1', fg='white',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in ["log₁₀","ln"]:
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='Light Cyan2', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in ["+","-","*",chr(247),"%","√","."]:
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='sienna', fg='white',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i in ["="]:
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='Light Pink', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i == "x!":
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='tomato', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        elif i == "e":
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='cadet blue', fg='grey20',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        else :
            button = Button(win, width=6, height=2, bd=2, text=i, bg='grey8', fg='white',
                        font=('garamond', 18, 'bold'), activebackground='cornflower blue', command=lambda button=i: click(button))
            button.grid(row=rowvalue, column=columnvalue,padx = 2, pady=2)
        
        
        columnvalue += 1
        if columnvalue > 7:
            rowvalue += 1
            columnvalue = 0

    # Here are the fucntions for ManuBar.

    def iExit():
        iExit = tk.messagebox.askyesno("Smart Calculator","Do you want to exit ?")
        if iExit>0:
            win.destroy()
            return


    menubar = Menu(win)

    # ManuBar 1 :

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = filemenu)
    filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = iExit)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

# create frames
tab1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)

tab1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
tab2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# add frames to notebook

notebook.add(tab1, text='Calculators')
notebook.add(tab2, text='Unit Converters')

cl1 = Label(tab1, text = "CALCULATORS", font= ("Stencil", 14), justify = 'center', bg = "Cornflower Blue",fg = "Grey4")
cl1.place(relx = '0.2', rely = '0.075')

cb1 = Button(tab1, text = "Standard", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood', command = Standard)
cb1.place(relx = '0.05', rely = '0.25')

cb2 = Button(tab1, text = "Scientific", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
cb2.place(relx = '0.45', rely = '0.25')

cb3 = Button(tab1, text = "Age", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
cb3.place(relx = '0.05', rely = '0.45')

cb4 = Button(tab1, text = "Date", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
cb4.place(relx = '0.45', rely = '0.45')

cb5 = Button(tab1, text = "BMI", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
cb5.place(relx = '0.05', rely = '0.65')

ul2 = Label(tab2, text = "UNIT CONVERTERS", font= ("Stencil", 14), justify = 'center', bg = "Cornflower Blue",fg = "Grey4")
ul2.place(relx = '0.2', rely = '0.075')

ub6 = Button(tab2, text = "Length", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
ub6.place(relx = '0.05', rely = '0.25')

ub7 = Button(tab2, text = "Mass", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
ub7.place(relx = '0.45', rely = '0.25')

ub8 = Button(tab2, text = "Volume", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
ub8.place(relx = '0.05', rely = '0.45')

ub9 = Button(tab2, text = "Temperature", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
ub9.place(relx = '0.45', rely = '0.45')

ub10 = Button(tab2, text = "Time", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
ub10.place(relx = '0.05', rely = '0.65')

ub11 = Button(tab2, text = "Digital", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
ub11.place(relx = '0.45', rely = '0.65')

ub12 = Button(tab2, text = "Currency", font = ("Garamond",14), width = 10,bg = 'Burlywood')
ub12.place(relx = '0.05', rely = '0.85')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code down to a [mcve]. I'm guessing almost all of those `if` statements and math functions aren't at all related to the problem.

Comment: i also have to do the Scientific calculator so i think that could be the minimal code

Comment: _You_ might need theses features, but _we_ do not need them to reproduce this problem. Your goal is to post the fewest lines of code possible that lets us reproduce your problem. I doubt that the `elif value == '='` block is necessary to reproduce the problem.